# How does the RPi Boot work?

Tags: boot, operating-systems, raspberry-pi-desktop

I am a complete beginner in Raspberry pi and have very little knowledge of the Operating system. So to put on the OS on my new Raspberry Pi I come across the "[RPi Boot](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-emmc-flashing.md)".

When I follow the steps as:

1. Connect a USB cable to my System and to the Raspberry Pi.
2. Open RPi Boot
3. Switch on the power supply.

As soon as I switch on the power supply something run on the RPi Boot window as shown:

[image]

After this, the above window disappears and Now I can see the "boot(F)" drive on the drive list of my system.

Now my question is as normal USB drive we can read and write the data on it by simply connecting to it to the system and we do not need the RPi Boot.

So why we need the RPi Boot when we use Raspberry Pi or any other board.

Comment: Never heard of Rpiboot

Comment: @Milliways SORRY it was my mistake it is RPi Boot here is the [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-emmc-flashing.md)

Comment: You should edit your question NOT put additional detail in Comments. If you are using a Compute Module you should tag this.